# Copy Files from yesterday date ans update that value in SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Need help.

1. There was a input folder with 5 files. when files exist that should reflect column verified to 1 in SQL DB table.

Sol: i have tried getmetadata- exist and if condition* to throw TRUE when file exist. BUT how we send TRUE value to DB Table.*

2. When files not exist have to copy file folder of last sys date.

Get meta to check file exist and if condtio to take decision used. How to send TRUE to DB when files exist ??

Comment: From where you are cheking files?

Comment: please can you explain little bit more about what you are exactly trying from where you are checking file exists or not?

Comment: Hi, I am checking gor csv-input folder which is there in one container. And its Blob storage

Comment: what do you mean by `copy file folder of last sys date`?

Comment: how you are concluding that which file should be exist in the folder?

Comment: can you share expected output from SQL table?

Answer (score 0):

> how we send TRUE value to DB Table.

To resolve your issue, you need update the value using script activity based upon get metadata result.

I assumed from information you have provided you have file table in SQL, and you are checking foreach file if it is existing in input folder or not if not copying file.

first get all files from sql table to check. with lookup activity I am gelling below output.
[image]

After this I am passing this output value to for each loop as `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`

[image]

Under foreach activity I took get metadata activity to check file exist or not in particular folder here I created `filename` **string** parameter. and passing `@item().filename` to dataset parameter.
[image]

and passing this output to if condition with `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.exists` if result of get meta data is true then it will execute true condition.

[image]

under if I took script activity to update value in SQL table.

```
@concat('update filetb set verified = 1 where filename = ''',item().filename,'''')
```

[image]

this query will update verified as 1 if filename exist.

Otherwise, control go to false condition and there you can put copy activity.
[image]

when get metadata is false control is going to false condition.